# Can Windows XP Recovery Console load drivers from a USB thumb drive?

Tags: windows, drivers, recovery-console

Must the drivers for Recovery Console be provided via a floppy diskette, or can I provide them via a USB drive?

Comment: You can not add drivers via USB, but you can pre-integrate them so you do not need to add any drivers. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

Try nLite.

You will need a Windows XP CD or ISO.  You can integrate drivers using nLite.  Then you have to make have nLite make a new ISO file.

Then use Unetbootin to transfer the ISO to make a bootable USB stick with your new drivers pre-integrated.

There is a manual way but it is very time consuming compare to nLite.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they must. If the machine lacks an inbuilt floppy drive, there are USB versions available, which if I recall correctly will work for this purpose.

Comment: Yes, I know of USB floppy drives. In my case, I don't have any kind of floppy drive or diskette, so I'm wondering if an ordinary thumb drive would work.